# How can I link a SQL database user to a different Windows based login?

Tags: sql-server

I am able to link a SQL database user to a Windows login with:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForProduction] FROM WINDOWS

CREATE USER MyDatabaseUser FOR LOGIN [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForProduction]
```

I can then grant permissions on objects to MyDatabaseUser and everything is cool.

I moved the database to the development server and tried this:

```
CREATE LOGIN [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForDevelopment] FROM WINDOWS

ALTER USER MyDatabaseUser WITH LOGIN = [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForDevelopment]
```

After I run this alter command the database user MyDatabaseUser is gone and a new database user named [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForDevelopment] is added to the database. This new database user is now linked to the login [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForDevelopment].

Is there a way to link the database user to the new login without having to drop and create him again?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying.  Was MyDatabaseUser already setup on the test server?

Comment: @w0051977 It was created in the database while on the production server. The database from backed up and moved from production to development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following instruction:

```
ALTER USER MyDatabaseUser WITH Name=MyDatabaseUser,
LOGIN = [DOMAIN01\MyLoginForDevelopment]
```

Comment: That worked! Why did someone down vote a perfectly good answer? I did try that option once and got an error about the SID for the user being different. I did not pay too much attention and just assumed this technique was not suitable. I cannot reproduce that problem now so I'll move ahead with this method. If I get that SID error again I'll come back here and update this.